# Dell e6400 and wifi problem

Tags: wireless, dell

I'm trying to run a Dell e6400 will Ubuntu and having no success with getting on wifi. I've tried all the stuff that I can understand after reading through the other threads. It all seems a bit old though. I've got a clean install of Ubuntu which I think adds to the problem I'm having.
If someone else out there has had this issue or knows the easiest fix I'd sure appreciate someone sharing it here.
Thanks,
Dean.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in terminal (CTRL+SHIFT+T)

```
lspci -vnn | grep 14e4
```

Once you've found the model of your wifi-driver go to this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported
to see if it is supported with Ubuntu.

Comment: I also get a 721 warning. Dangit.

Answer (score 0):

That laptop has a physical switch to turn on and off the wifi and the bluetooth, are you sure it is ON ?

I have installed Ubuntu in that laptop many times and always successful to use the wifi.